# Resetting setInterval timer for three different interval buttons

Tags: javascript, html, timer, dom-events, setinterval

**Problem:** I have three buttons that set different timers. When I click the timer buttons after a first click, it doesn't reset the timer, but continues the timer where it left off.

**Desired Result:** When I click the timer buttons (Pomodoro, lng break, shrt break) I want the timer to reset. EG: Pomodoro is set for 24mins 60seconds. If I click the same Pomodoro button when the timer is say, 23 mins, I want it to reset to the original 24mins, 60 seconds.

**Re-created the situation:**

Here is my javascript, and html. I will also post a JSBin since I am still not sure how to do code snippets yet.

**JavaScript:**

```
//  Problem: Pomodor timer does not have functionality
//  Solution: Add functionality to the pomodor timer.
//      IF a break timer is running WHILE another is clicked, stop running timer, start clicked timer.
//      Reset current interval time on reset button.
//      If break buttons are clicked more than once, reset the time.
window.onload = function() {

    var pomodoro = document.querySelector('#set-time'),
        longBreak = document.querySelector('#long-brk'),
        shortBreak = document.querySelector('#short-brk'),
        stopButton = document.querySelector('#stop'),
        startButton = document.querySelector('#start'),
        resetButton = document.querySelector('#reset'),
        container = document.querySelector('#container'),
        timer = document.querySelector('#timer'),
        seconds = 60;  //set seconds
   //  Click event for break timers.    
    container.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
//      store event target
        var el = e.target;
            if (el === pomodoro) {
                setPomodoro();
            } else if (el === longBreak) {
                setLongBreak();
            } else if (el === shortBreak) {
                setShortBreak();
            }
            e.stopPropagation();
    }, false);  
//  1.1a Create a timer that counts down from 25 minutes.
    function setPomodoro() {
        var pomodoroMins = 24;
        var intervalID = setInterval(function() { //set unique interval ID for each SI func.
                timer.innerHTML = pomodoroMins + ':' + seconds;
                seconds--;
                if (seconds === 0) {
                    pomodoroMins--;
                    seconds = 60;
                } 
            }, 1000);
//      2.2 When stop button is clicked, timer stops
        stopButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }, false);
    }
//  1.2a Create a timer that counts down from 10 minutes
    function setLongBreak() {
        var longBreakMins = 9;
        var intervalID2 = setInterval(function() {
                timer.innerHTML = longBreakMins + ':' + seconds;
                seconds--;
                if (seconds === 0) {
                    longBreakMins--;
                    seconds = 60;
                }
            }, 1000);
         stopButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            clearInterval(intervalID2);
        }, false);
    }
//  1.3a Create a timer that counts down from 5 minutes.
    function setShortBreak() {
        var shortBreakMins = 4;
        var intervalID3 = setInterval(function() {
                timer.innerHTML = shortBreakMins + ':' + seconds;
                seconds--;
                if (seconds === 0) {
                    shortBreakMins--;
                    seconds = 60;
                }
            }, 1000);
        stopButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            clearInterval(intervalID3);
        }, false);
    }
};
```

**HTML:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pomodoro Timer</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <div id="header"><h1>Pomodoro Timer</h1></div>
        </header>
        <div class="row">
            <ul id="breaks">
                <li><input type="submit" value="Pomodoro" id="set-time"></li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="Long Break" id="long-brk"></li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="Short Break" id="short-brk"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h1 id=timer></h1>
        <div class="row">
            <ul id="buttons">
                <li><input type="submit" value="Start" id="start"></li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="Stop" id="stop"></li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="Reset" id="reset"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; Laere 2016</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JSBin:** http://jsbin.com/fodagejohi/1/edit?html,js,output

Appreciate the guidance.

Comment: You need separate `seconds` counters for each timer; currently they're all sharing the same one.

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot. I didn't even consider giving each timer their own seconds variable. It does what I wanted it to do. Thanks a lot man. I still have tons to learn!